# Conditional formatting for columns, date & time specific?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

[image: screenshot of data in google sheets]

I have uploaded 4.000+ Venmo donation data sets into Google Sheets for sorting, but the date and time is preset and looks like this:

```
2018-11-01T20:16:52
```

I have tried multiple approaches to sorting and formatting these but to no avail.

Ideally I would like to have date and time separate, but if need be I could drop the time and have the date only.

I am using column B, rows 2-4006.

I think if I can successfully set a conditional format for the entire column of =10 characters (or perhaps <11 ??) I could then possibly sort the format data to a date time format that I prefer (so from 2018-11-01 to 11/01/18).

If this makes sense to anyone and you can offer some suggestions, please feel free to message me!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that **T** in `2018-11-01T20:16:52`

and the solution is to insert a new column after **B** column and paste this into **C2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B4000<>"",
             MID(B2:B4000,6,2)&"/"&
             MID(B2:B4000,9,2)&"/"&
             MID(B2:B4000,3,2),))
```

[image]

for time separation use:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IF(B2:B4000<>"",
                           MID(B2:B4000,6,2)&"/"&
                           MID(B2:B4000,9,2)&"/"&
                           MID(B2:B4000,3,2)&" "&
                         RIGHT(B2:B4000,8),), " ")),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(B2:B4000, "T"))
```

The date and time are shown automatically in the adjoining columns.

Answer (score 0):

Formula

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(B2:B,"T"),COUNTA(B2:B),1))
```

To separate date-time values formatted as `2018-11-01T20:16:52` (text values)

- use `SPLIT`

  - use an open-ended reference (`B2:B`)to split values added lately without having to edit the formula
  - use `T` as separator.
- use `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` to return split the values of non-empty cells.

  - Use `COUNTA` to calculate the how many cells on `B2:B` have text values.
- use `ARRAYFORMULA` to return an array of values instead of a single value.